# How to query, "If this column contains 'this' then replace text in another column"

Tags: sql

Within a 'Select'-based query, I would like to include an expression that says: If Column B = 'Call', replace everything in Column A with 'Call'.

I have tried the When-Then expression:

```
 Column A = (CASE column a
 When 'Business' Then 'Call'
```

But that will change every Business entry in Column A when Column B doesn't have 'Call'.

I figured that I'd need an If statement or so, but don't know how to use it across columns.

This is my simplified query:

```
 Select *
 From [crimes]
 Where date_rept between '1/1/2019' and '1/31/2019'
 And column B in ('Call', 'Case')
```

This is what I Have:

```
 COLUMN A          COLUMN B
```

```
 Natural           Case
 Business          Call
 Park              Call
 Business          Case
```

This is what I Want:

```
 COLUMN A          COLUMN B
```

```
 Natural           Case
 Call              Call
 Call              Call
 Business          Case
```

I expect for each 'Call' in Column B to be copied into Column A.

Pardon my lack of knowledge. I do not wish to edit the actual data table, but only wish to view data based on my parameters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you guys so much! The 'case' expression was a go!

Comment: you can mark any if the question which helped you as per your comment above!!! if that helped community should have more of correct answers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
update t
    set a = b
    where b = 'Call';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the Update statement as I cannot manipulate the data within the table. I can only query the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `case` expression will also work, you just missed out the `else` clause  &  condition `columnB = 'Call'` :

```
CASE WHEN columna = 'Business' AND columnB = 'Call' THEN 'Call' ELSE columna END AS ColumnA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference other columns from within a case statement:

```
select
  case when B = 'Call' then 'Call' else A end as A,
  B
from [Crimes]
Where 
  date_rept between '1/1/2019' and '1/31/2019'
  and B in ('Call', 'Case')
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
Select case when columnB='Call' the 'Call' else columnA end
From [crimes]
Where date_rept between '1/1/2019' and '1/31/2019'
And column B in ('Call', 'Case')
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need an else statemente like this:

```sql
(CASE WHEN columnb = 'Call' THEN 'Call' ELSE columna END) AS "Column A"
```

Of course you have to adapt syntax to your SQL dialact (which you didn't mention) but that's the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work!

```sql
Select case when c.B = 'Call' Then 'Call' Else c.A End, c.B
 From crimes as c
 Where date_rept between '1/1/2019' and '1/31/2019'
 AND B in ('Call', 'Case')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work..

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COLUMN_B= 'Call' THEN 'CALL' ELSE COLUMN_A END AS COLUMN_A,
COLUMN_B
FROM CRIMES
WHERE DATE_REPT BETWEEN '1/1/2019' AND '1/31/2019'
AND COLUMN_B IN ('Call', 'Case')
```